# Connection Timed Out when attempting to connect to an Aurora DB from a second VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

I have two VPCs in the same account and the same Availability Zone.  In the **first VPC I have an EC2 instance and a Aurora DB** (which has a single Endpoint and a Cluster Endpoint).  In the **second VPC I have another EC2 instance**.

The first EC2 instance **can connect** to the Aurora DB Cluster Endpoint with no issues (again; both in the same VPC).  **I'm trying to connect the second EC2 instance (in the second VPC) to the same Aurora DB Cluster Endpoint (in the first VPC)**.

The first VPC has CIDR of 172.31.0.0/16.  The second VPC has a CIDR of 10.0.0.0/28.  Both VPCs have DNS hostnames set to Yes.  I am **not** using IAM database authentication.

I created a VPC Peering Connection, and the connection reports itself as being Active.  The connection has the correct VPCs in it's Route Table and "Allow DNS resolution from peer VPC () to Private IP" is checked for both VPCs.   The first VPC is the default and has 3 subnets.  The second VPC has one subnet.

But the second EC2 instance (in the second VPC) times out when it tries to connect to the Aurora DB.  I'm using the same Cluster Endpoint name in the second EC2 instance as I'm using in the first.  Both EC2 instances are using exactly the same connection strings.

Comment: Security group settings? Network ACLs changed from defaults?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: I think you may be right about the Security Group settings.  I didn't see what I expected to see when I configured the security group for the additional ec2 instance/aurora db; in that I expected to see the ids of the other VPC as available targets.  

However; I found that I could do what I wanted to do by not using a second VPC and, as I couldn't make the Peering connection work I went the single VPC route instead.  I'm going to leave this question here in case someone has some useful advice for others.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Im stuck at trying to get a cross account / cross region vpc peering. I believe ive got this set right including VPC, route tables and security groups. (I hope) I havent touched the Network ACL's. Should i be modifying that ?